# Howto place selectbox and inputbox on the same line?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, drop-down-menu

I have a small select box and an input box.  But unfortunately the select box is over the input box.

Here is the code:

```
<select style="width:50px;height:20px;margin-left:30px">
<option selected="selected">Please select</option>
<option>1</option>
</select>
<input type='text' name='test' style="width: 210px;"value='' />
```

How can I place both on the same row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want them on the same row, then enclose them in a div:

```
<div>
  <select style="width:50px;height:20px;margin-left:30px">
    <option selected="selected">Please select</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <input type='text' name='test' style="width: 210px;"value='' />
</div>
```